# How to make Switching button in Laravel Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, button

> how to make button when i click On-progress Button it show a
>   modal. then once I save the button will change into
>   "button Return" "button On sale"
>   Im Using laravel with vuejs  ...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand.

What will the 2 second buttons do? using `v-show` and `v-if/else`

```
<template>
    <section>
        <div v-show="showModal" class="modal">
            <button @click="save">Save</button>
        </div>
        <div v-if="saved">
            <button>button Return</button>
            <button>button on sale</button>
        </div>
        <div else>
            <button @click="toggleModal">On-progress</button>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            saved: false,
            showModal: false,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        toggleModal() {
            this.showModal = !this.showModal;
        },
        save() {
            this.saved = true;
            this.toggleModal();
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me an Idea how to do it :)